# Python create a dict from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using django 1.8, Python 2.7.5, [django-datatables-view 1.2](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view/src/d816956c433d3e0cd3392632759cdb6b7867e394/django_datatables_view/base_datatable_view.py?at=master#cl-174), and [datatables 1.10.6](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/). When trying to use [columndefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) and [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) I am getting the following error:

Warning: Requested unknown...

I looked up the documentation on this [here](https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) and basically figured out that datatables has no idea what data I am requesting because it cannot find it. So I looked at how the data was being returned:

```
{
    "recordsTotal": 176,
    "recordsFiltered": 176,
    "draw": 0,
    "data": [
        [
            109,
            "Hostname1",
            "1.1.1.1",
            "Excluded",
            "Down"
        ],
        [
            116,
            "Hostname2",
            "2.2.2.2",
            "Excluded",
            "Up"
        ],
        ...
    ],
    "result": "ok"
}
```

So I have worked with datatables before using PHP and in order to work with column def you need a key:value pair so that you can define `"data": "Key"` which obviously this is not. I think I have narrowed down what is building the prepared results to this:

```
def prepare_results(self, qs):
    data = []
    for item in qs:
        data.append([self.render_column(item, column) for column in self.get_columns()])
    return data
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to convert this list of lists to a dictionary that returns the results in the following manner:

```
{
    "recordsTotal": 176,
    "recordsFiltered": 176,
    "draw": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "Rest Id": "109",
            "Host Name": "Hostname1",
            "Ip Address": "1.1.1.1",
            "Mode": "Excluded",
            "State": "Down"
        },
        {
            "Rest Id": "116",
            "Host Name": "Hostname2",
            "Ip Address": "2.2.2.2",
            "Mode": "Excluded",
            "State": "Up"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "result": "ok"
}
```

I understand that I could possibly accomplish what I am trying to do with dict comprehension but I can't figure out a way to get it exactly the way I am looking to have the output returned. I also have to believe there is a better way of doing this than doing a dict comprehension on a list of lists after it has already been prepared. Any and all help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize but I sort of solved my own issue via datatables javascript directly instead of making the changes in the python code:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": 0,
        "data": 0,
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return '<span data-clipboard-text="' + data + '">' + String(data) + '</span>' + 
            '<a href="URLICANNOTSHARE' + data + 
            'MOREOFTHEURLICANNOTSHARE" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button" target="_blank" style="float:right;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>';
            },
    },
    ....
],
```

Also I brain fubar'd what I was saying above and what I should have said is that by default datatables *expects* a javascript object (at least every example they have shows the data being parsed is an object) but what I was returning was a javascript array (still works if you have half a brain, which I did not). Will leave open though to see if an python solution could be provided.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your datas are into a `datas` variable, you can do the following :

```
keys = ["Rest Id", "Host Name", "Ip Address", "Mode", "State"]
datas["data"] = [dict(zip(keys, d)) for d in datas["data"]]
```

Comment: When I try to add that perpare_results function above it tells me that `global name 'datas' is not defined`. When I simpy try to add the fields list and return `[dict(zip(keys, d)) for d in data["data"]]` it tells me `list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: What is the variable that contains all the datas you printed in your question ?

Comment: It should just be 'data'. See [here](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view/src/d816956c433d3e0cd3392632759cdb6b7867e394/django_datatables_view/base_datatable_view.py?at=master#cl-174) Lines 174 - 240 are where the magic is happening, but the data looks like it is prepared in the `prepare_results` function.

Comment: Actually it looks like `prepare_results` builds the `data` list but `get_context_data` dumps that into an array called `ret` and that is what returns the output above.

Comment: So `"data": [
        [
            109,
            "Hostname1",
            "1.1.1.1",
            "Excluded",
            "Down"
        ], [...]]` is build by `prepare_results` ?